# Why does Happy from "Fairy Tail" have wings?

Tags: fairy-tail

I was watching *Fairy Tail* the other day and I was like, hey why does Happy have wings? He's a cat. jeez. also, like, how can he fly Natsu around? He's puny.

Comment: Fairy Tail is fictional, and it has magic as its main theme. The 'normal' things in real life don't usually apply to shows like these.

Answer (score 5):

Because Happy isn't a cat, he's an Exceed and his wings are a result of the spell Aera which Exceeds have.

> [Aera](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Aera) (翼エーラ Ēra): Happy is able to sprout angelic wings that give him the ability to fly and carry objects or one person at a time for a specific amount of time.

Source: [Happy > Magic and Abilities (1st dot point)](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Happy#Magic_and_Abilities)